# SearchBar Assistance-React

Tags: reactjs

So I am trying to set a searchbar that has a drop down menu that gives you options on what you want to search for=and then let the user input.  I have a list of inspections that I want to base that on.
For example I want to search inspections that only have issues with pests, so the user selects the pest option for search and then inputs-hive beetles
so the dropdown should have an option of searching by: pests, notes, actions taken, and so forth, my table has 8 values that I want to specific each search.
I have am using React for this and my database is in django, any suggestions on how to tackle this?  The research I found is not really helpful.

My InpsectionSearch

```
import {React, useState} from "react";


const SearchInspections = (inspections) => {

    const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState("")
    const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([])
    

    function handleChange(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        const filteredInspections = inspections.filter((inspections) => {
            return (
                inspections.eggs().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()) ||
                inspections.larvae().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()) ||
                inspections.sealed_brood().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()) ||
                inspections.covered_bees().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()) ||
                inspections.nectar_honey().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()) ||
                inspections.pollen().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()) ||
                inspections.pest_spotted.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()) ||
                inspections.pest_action.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()) ||
                inspections.notes_concerns.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())
               
            )
        })
        setSearchResults(filteredInspections)
        if(searchField.length > 0){
           inspections(searchResults)
        }
    }

    return ( 
        <form onSubmit={handleChange}>
            <h3>Search For Your Item</h3>
            <input type="search" placeholder='Search Song' value={searchField} onChange={event => setSearchField(event.target.value)}/>
            <button type='submit'>Click twice to search</button>
        </form>
     );
}

export default SearchInspections;
```

my Inspection Page where the searchbar will be

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import useAuth from "../../hooks/useAuth";
import DisplayInspections from "../../components/DisplayInspections/DisplayInspections";
import InspectionTracker from "../../components/InspectionTracker/InspectionTracker";
import SearchInspections from "../../components/InspectionSearch/InspectionSearch"

const InspectionPage = (props) => {
  const [user, token] = useAuth();
  const [inspections, setInspections] = useState([]);
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchInspections();
  }, [token]);

  const fetchInspections = async () => {
    try {
      let response = await axios.get(
        `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/inspections/all/${id}`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
          },
        }
      );
      setInspections(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
    }
  };

  function applyFilter(category, userInput){
    if(category === 'All' || userInput ===''){
    console.log('working!')
    fetchInspections();
    }
    else
    {
      let newInspections = inspections.filter(function(element){
        if(element[category] === userInput){
          return true;
        }
      })
      setInspections(newInspections);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <InspectionTracker inspections={inspections} />
      <SearchInspections inspections={inspections} />
      <DisplayInspections
        inspections={inspections}
        setSelectedHive={props.setSelectedHive}
        setSelectedInspection={props.setSelectedInspection}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default InspectionPage;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? As a starting point, you would need to keep track of your filters in state. You can do your filtering on the frontend if it is simple enough (if you are creating your table dynamically with `Array.map()` for instance, you can just add filtering logic in there), or selecting a filter can make a new request to your backend with the filter as a parameter. You can filter with django and return a new array of the filtered inspections.

Comment: I have edited my comment to reflect the code I created for this--so now I'm not sure how 1. give the bar each field option above, to give the user to specifically search by whichever row they want.

Comment: When you say "field option", do you mean 8 categories? You want the user to 1) select a category 2) search within that category, right? The category can be handled by a `<select>` input with hardcoded or programmatically generated values, and the search can be handled by another `<input type="text">`. Both inputs should be saved in state

Comment: Yes that is correct, 8 Categories

Comment: In your component definition `const SearchInspections = (inspections)` shouldn't it be `const SearchInspections = ({inspections})` ?

Comment: You are correct, that is fixed!